# In the case of emergency replacing printers

Tags: printing, printer, windows-server-2019

we've got two same printers (HP E60155), one for use in WMS, second one in office. This one from office in case of emergency will be move to warehouse. Remote devices to scan barcodes are on remote terminal server. E.g. first printer has IP x.x.x.70, second has x.x.x.120. Is there any possibility to make one-click configuration button to change these IP's on printer or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a duplicate printer you keep on hand in case something goes wrong with the first one.  You want to be able to literally unplug one printer, and plug in the other one and have no interruption for anything trying to connect to it.  Your assumption (which may or may not be correct, depending), is that the only issue would be the IP address.  Literally, everything else is the same.  It also sounds like the replacement printer is in regular use before the swap.

What I would do is shut off DHCP on the printers, and manually assign them IPs.  This would take place on the printer itself.  I would make sure those IPs are reserved.  That would take place on my router.  Then, I just have to assign a new manual IP on the printer before I unplug it, then when I plug it in again, the network would (hopefully) think one is the other.

There are a lot of assumptions here, and a lot of "it depends."  For instance, print jobs that were already spooled to the broken printer will likely have issues.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you can see here in hp web jetadmin you can create a configuration template and apply it.  You can also schedule it.

So maybe you could create some additional automation based on this.

Also here:
[image]